# Read and save multiple csv files from a for-loop

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am trying to read multiple csv files from a list of file paths and save them all as separate pandas dataframes.

I feel like there should be a way to do this, however I cannot find a succinct explanation.

```
import pandas as pd

data_list = [['df_1','filepath1.csv'],
             ['df_2','filepath2.csv'],
             ['df_3','filepath3.csv']]

for name, filepath in data_list:
    name = pd.read_csv(filepath)
```

I have also tried:

```
data_list = [[df_1,'filepath1.csv'],[df_2,'filepath2.csv'],
             [df_3,'filepath3.csv']]

for name, filepath in data_list:
    name = pd.read_csv(filepath)
```

I would like to be able to call each dataframe by its assigned name.

Ex):

```
df_1.head()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df_dct = {name:pd.read_csv(filepath) for name, filepath in data_list}
```

would create a dictionary of DataFrames.  This may help you organize your data.

You may also want to look into [glob.glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) to create your list of files.  For example, to get all CSV files in a directory:

```
file_paths = glob.glob(my_file_dir+"/*.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you numpy. Read the csv files with numpy.

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
my_data = genfromtxt('my_file.csv', delimiter=',')
```

You will get nd-array's. After that you can include them into pandas.

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure of dictionary for this...

```
import pandas as pd
data_list = ['filepath1.csv', 'filepath2.csv', 'filepath3.csv']
d = {}
for _, i in enumerate(data_list):
    file_name = "df" + str(_)
    d[file_name] = pd.read_csv(filepath)
```

Here `d` is the dictionary which contains all your dataframes.